# if I run a .py script, can I open a new terminal, modify the file and run it also?

Tags: python

if I run a .py script, can I open a new terminal, modify the file and run it also?

i.e. does the file that I run get loaded in memory, such that I can modify the file and run it at the same time in a different terminal?

Comment: I'm running a very long script, for production use, and don't want to ruin the process flow. thanks.

Comment: You could try with a short script in a non-production environment. Generally, I wouldn't trust something that I read on the Internet when I am messing with my production environment. You should really try it for yourself, if possible in another environment.

Comment: I agree with @relet that if you're running a long script for production use, then it's best to make the modification in a different environment. Is it possible for you to instantiate a virtual environment for the production and/or development (e.g., VirtualBox)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Here's my original test code.

```
while 1:
    print "This is the original."
```

Here's the modified code:

```
while 1:
    print "This is modified."
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  Is this a hard thing to test yourself?

Comment: Maybe that is the question: Can *he*?